# How do I remove .net CryptoStream padding

Tags: c#

When I use the following class the output is padded.

```
public static string EncryptString(string ClearText) {
  byte[] clearTextBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ClearText);
  System.Security.Cryptography.SymmetricAlgorithm rijn = SymmetricAlgorithm.Create();
  MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
  byte[] rgbIV = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("ryojvlzmdalyglrj");
  byte[] key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("hcxilkqbbhczfeultgbskdmaunivmfuo");            
  CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, rijn.CreateEncryptor(key, rgbIV),
           CryptoStreamMode.Write);
  cs.Write(clearTextBytes, 0, clearTextBytes.Length);
  cs.Close();
  return Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
}

public static string DecryptString(string EncryptedText)
        {
  byte[] encryptedTextBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(EncryptedText);

  MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

  System.Security.Cryptography.SymmetricAlgorithm rijn = SymmetricAlgorithm.Create();
  rijn.Mode = CipherMode.CFB;

  byte[] rgbIV = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("ryojvlzmdalyglrj");
  byte[] key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("hcxilkqbbhczfeultgbskdmaunivmfuo"); ;

  CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, rijn.CreateDecryptor(key, rgbIV),
  CryptoStreamMode.Write);

  cs.Write(encryptedTextBytes, 0, encryptedTextBytes.Length);

  cs.Close();

  return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());
}
```

I understood from another post that there is

```
rijn.Padding = PaddingMode.None;
```

When I added this I get an error that says "Length of the data to encrypt is invalid"

Even when I try to encrypt a 6 byte string then I see get a long result.

```
var def1 = Encrypt.EncryptString("abcdefg");
```

gives me 24 bytes!

Can someone give me some advice here.

UPDATE

Changed to the following:

```
        byte[] bytOut = ms.GetBuffer();
        int i = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < bytOut.Length; i++)
            if (bytOut[i] == 0)
                break;

        // convert into Base64 so that the result can be used in xml

        return System.Convert.ToBase64String(bytOut, 0, i);
```

When I check bytOut it's 16bytes Then the value returned after ToBase64 is 24 bytes. I am still not sure why the size is so large

Comment: I'm no expert, but it's possible that the encryption algorithm cannot securely work with as few as 6 bytes.

Comment: When encrypting a string of 12 bytes it gives me an output that's 24 bytes long.

Comment: what encryption algorithm is this? the only thing i can think of that uses less than 8 bytes is a stream cipher, but that wouldnt account for the error or the fact that you are using a symmetric algorithm

Comment: System.Security.Cryptography.SymmetricAlgorithm

Comment: Thats really not helpful

Comment: The output needs to be a factor of blocksize. IIRC Rijndeal is 64 bytes.

Comment: 64 **bits**. Actually, Rijndael can have block sizes of 32,64 or 128 bits. AES is specifically 128 bits though.

Comment: I see there are different options such as Aes DES RC2 Rijindael TripleDES. I just picked this one because I found an example on the internet. Is there one of these that would allow me to have a shorter output string. Also I don't expect a lot of details but what are the differences? Is one recommended over another for very simple encryption?

Comment: @Mark H: Thanks for correction  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the [mode of operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation). The default is Cipher Block Chaining (CBC), which requires each block match up the block size of the algorithm, and padding to be used if necessary.

You can use another mode. Take CFB for example, it will internally pad your data before doing the plain ECB mode, and cut off the padding when it returns your result. (and do some clever stuff with the IVs so that you can continue to use the cipher without padding.) But it seems suitable for your case.

```
rijn.Mode = CipherMode.CFB;
```

Comment: I added this and tested it out. I still get an output of 24 bytes :-(   Is the length of the output related to the IV length?

Comment: @Emily: The IV length shuold be equal to the blocksize of the algorithm, so yes, it's related in CBC mode and such. I think the problem of your function returning 24 bytes is more likely to be the way in which you're using ms.ToArray(), which will return the size of the buffer allocated internally in the MemoryStream. Just read the bytes you need from it instead.

Comment: I added some comments to the question. Still giving 16 bytes and then after the base64 this changes it to 24. I'm confused now.

Comment: Marking as accepted but I'm still confused. I will look into this in more detail. Thanks everyone for your help.

Comment: @Emily: Rather than reading from the MS until you find \0, you should be able to read encryptedBytesText.Length number of bytes (when using CFB). The padding can be discarded with CFB mode, provided the same IV is used. As for the size increasing when using base64 - that's bound to happen, since in base64, each byte can only hold 64 values, as opposed to the 256 values each byte can hold in the byte array. Base64 is necessary when transferring a byte[] over a protocol which only expects ASCII, but if your protocol supports binary, just use the byte[].

Answer (score 0):

Encryption algorithms work in blocks. It will always round up to the nearest block size. You just need a well-defined padding algorithm, so you can correctly remove the padding after decryption.

Comment: The problem is storage. I need to have the output string as small as possible. Is there a better algorithm I could use. I see there are some different algorithm's.

Comment: You can use an System.Security.Cryptography.TripleDES instead of SymmetricAlgorithm. This will give you half the block size. Also, if you don't strictly need to, you can store the raw bytes, not the base64 encoded version.